# Need query for a flexible search in elasticsearch version 7

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I want a Elasticsearch query which I can run in Kibana, it want it for free text, for example if I want to search for "JOHN" then all the records having value "JOHN" should be fetched, Even if JOHN@gmail.com is there it should get that, and the query should also works for number, if I am searching for "008" then all records having 008 should be fetched and if none of the records contains "008" then results should be zero,

In my previous version of elasticsearch i was using the below query

```
"bool":{"must":[{"match_phrase_prefix":{"_all":"test"}}]}}
```

this query was very exactly how i wanted but after upgrading to elastic search version 7 its not working

Comment: Which version were you using before?

Comment: before it was version 5, and now 7.3